# How to rotate an imageview by touch in android & also increase the width of the imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to rotate an `ImageView` by finger touch.
[image]

but currently it is rotating circular from center point of the image.

```
public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
    wheel.setRotation((int)event.getRawX());
}
```

Comment: calculate angle between you have first touch and moving points then rotate it from center.

Comment: sir, please post the code

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code inside your onClickListener.

```
RotateAnimation rotateImage = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90,
                        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);

    rotateImage.setStartOffset(0);
    rotateImage.setDuration(1500); 
    rotateImage.setFillAfter(true);
    rotateImage.setInterpolator(YourActivity.this, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator);

    imageView.startAnimation(rotateImage);
```